# Response from python post request different from chrome network

Tags: python

I'm just learning about the request module in python and want to test it.
First I started looking at the chrome network tab to see the request URL and method: **POST** and the used form data, looking at the response tab on the chrome gives me the expected data in JSON but after doing it on a python file like this:

```
import requests

uid = "23415191"
url = "https://info.gbfteamraid.fun/web/userrank"

honors = requests.post(url, data={
    "method": "getUserDayPoint", 
    "params": {"teamraidid":"teamraid056","userid":uid}
}).text
print(honors)
```

This gives me a HTML elements of the homepage of the site instead of the JSON response, also used postman and it gives me the same result

Comment: What is the JSON response you were expecting?

Comment: {"msg":"","result":[{"updatedate":"2021-04-13","minp":"834237994","maxp":"1201981470"},{"updatedate":"2021-04-12","minp":"502318904","maxp":"834237994"},{"updatedate":"2021-04-11","minp":"350902968","maxp":"502318904"},{"updatedate":"2021-04-10","minp":"161184654","maxp":"350902968"},{"updatedate":"2021-04-09","minp":"123733704","maxp":"161184654"},{"updatedate":"2021-04-08","minp":"25501962","maxp":"123733704"},{"updatedate":"2021-04-07","minp":"2312978","maxp":"18391425"}],"err":"0"}

Comment: You should add that to your post, comments are less visible and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You are being redirected to a different page ,maybe cos you are not authenticated .Most probably you may need to authenticate your request . I have added the basic auth ,which uses id and password.Try this with the id ,pass that you have for that website and then see if it works. Just replace your  and  with your id and password.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

uid = "11111111"
url = "https://info.gbfteamraid.fun/web/userrank"

honors = requests.post(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username="<your username>",password="<your password>"), data={
    "method": "getUserDayPoint", 
    "params": {"teamraidid":"teamraid056","userid":uid}
}).text
print(honors)
```

Comment: oh the site doesn't input login info, there's just a button on the homepage for the kinda "login". Thanks anyway will keep Auth in mind